# mysql function, return name instead of id

Tags: php, mysql, database, function, parsing

Hi I have Table tbl_itemlist with

```
id | itemName | suppliers
1  | uSDReader| 1,2,3,4,5
```

the suppliers column contains comma delimited value
ex: (1,2,3,4,5)

Which correspond to suppliers name from other table tbl_supplier

```
id | supplierName
1  | Supplier 1
2  | Supplier 2
3  | Supplier 3
4  | Supplier 4
5  | Supplier 5
```

Is there any builtin function of MySQL that when I query using SELECT the itemlist table, something like JOINs, supplier column will return the name instead of supplier's id only. 
ex:

```
 id | itemName | suppliers
 1  | uSDReader| Supplier 1,Supplier 2,Supplier 3,Supplier 4,Supplier 5
```

Comment: See [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3653574)

Comment: Incredibly bad design: you really should normalize your database

Comment: _Spoiler: the answer is __yes__._

Comment: you are abusing MySQL with such a schema

Comment: Any best way to do that? I can redisign the schema,  'comma delimited is just my ex.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You indeed have a really bad MySQL schema. You have to create 3 tables named as `tbl_itemlist`, `tbl_suppliers`, `tbl_itemsupplies`.

`tbl_itemslist` and `tbl_suppliers` are the same as yours with tbl_itemslist with suppliers column deleted.

Your new table, `tbl_itemsupplies`, must contain these exact columns: `id`, `item_id`, `supplier_id`

You can check which suppliers does have the item with a simple query like:

```
SELECT `supplier_id` FROM tbl_itemsupplies WHERE `item_id`= {$itemid}
```